# java How create a child instance from parent class

Tags: java, android

I´m new in Java, and I´m creating several classes but I have one problem I don´t know how I can do for creating an unkown child from parent class. 
for example that is not the real case.

```
public class Father{
    public static Father winstance = null;
    public Context context;

    public static <child extends Father> child getInstance(Context context) {
    if (winstance == null)   {
           // here how have I to create child instance?
            winstance = new child(context); // here I have "Cannot instantiate the type child" error
    }
    winstance.context = context;
    return winstance;
    }

    public Father(Context pcontext) {
    context = pcontext;
    }
}
```

and at other part of code I will do some like that :

```
class Son extends Father {

    public Son(Context context) {
       super(context);
       // do something else
    }
}

    public Son son = null;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    son = Son.getInstance(this);
```

How could I create in parent a child instance that is unkown for parent? I have several base classes that I would need to do that.

thanks for helping.

Comment: Why does `Son` extend `Father`? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: it´s a fool example, it´s not real case, it could be A instead of Father and B instead of Son. I want to build several classes and class base I want do some generic code. My question is how I could do a "new" of an unkown child in parent that extends from?

Comment: If you are using generics the constructor looks something like: `V instance = (V) ((Class)((ParameterizedType)this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]).newInstance();`   You'll want something similar but using `getSuperclass()`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried the code above but "this" clause I can not use it at static method. I would like create a subclass from its parent one. Could you write how I could do with my above example. Thanks